# how to dynamically get the context-root of another web module within the same EAR/application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, websphere

My applications contains two web modules as follows:

```
<module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>myWeb1.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>/web1</context-root>
    </web>
</module>
<module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>myWeb2.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>/web2</context-root>
    </web>
</module>
```

,and I need to forward a request from "web1" module to "web2" as shown below.

```
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getContext("/web2").getRequestDispatcher("/servlets/actReq");
        rd.forward(request, response);
```

The question is, is it possible to retrieve the context-root name: "web2", insteading of harcoding this in the code. The reason why I dont want to hardcode the context-root, is because this can change during deployment of the EAR package.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At some point in time you must know you're destinations context root. Just add the name to a properties file or something similar...

Comment: One possible solution perhaps is to add it to a servlet init-param but just wondered if it was possible to dynamically get the value before going down this root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do that directly. This kind of direct app-to-app, or even servlet-to-servlet, communication is gently discouraged by the specification.

What you could do is add a simple servlet to each app that is marked `load-on-startup`, and which captures the context path in its init method and stores it somewhere. You could perhaps inject an EJB which collects context paths. Something like (very rough sketch!):

```
@Singleton
public class ContextPaths extends HashMap<String, String> {}

public class RegisterContextPath extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    private ContextPaths contextPaths;

    public void init() {
        String contextPath = getServletContext().getContextPath();
        contextPaths.put("myWeb1", contextPath);
    }
}
```

The servlet which wants to do the dispatch can then also be injected with the EJB, and do a lookup in it.

Note that you can't use a CDI `@ApplicationScoped` for this, because the application scope isn't active during `init()` (i think).

You could probably use a lifecycle listener of some sort to do the registration, rather than the servlet.

You could probably be a bit clever about the map keys too - use `getServletContextName()` and then rely on `display-name` being set in the web.xml? Use an init parameter? Ideally, you would have a single class that you could use in all your web apps, just configured differently.

Comment: Thanks Tom, this is certainly a very good recommendation and will go down this root should I see the necessity. @ the moment both war's are kind of managed by two different teams, :). So, for now if I can get away with just making changes to my war, I am happy: But I certainly will keep this solution up my sleeves.

Comment: Ah, i see. Yet another idea would be to write a `ServletContainerInitializer` and put it in a jar outside both the web apps (so an ejb-jar or something), where i think it will be notified of the startup of both your web apps. Not certain about that, though.